# FILE pointer in C not returning NULL

Tags: c, linux, file

I am aware that this is a question that is asked very often, and I am hoping that someone here can help me fix this...

This is a very simple segment of code, I am trying to open a file, and the file does not exist. I want to then handle this error as needed and move along however the file pointer created a segmentation fault when I try to compare it to NULL...see my code below:

```
FILE* file = fopen(res, "r");
if(file == NULL)
{
    printf("NO CONFIG FILE");
    return 0;
}
```

Even though the file pointed to by res is not present, a segmentation fault occurs when making this comparison if(file==NULL), is also fails if I use if(file==0). I am really at my wits end here and any input would be appreciated!

Just a quick update here...

When I remove the code to check the validity of the file pointer, and the file is there, the code works properly. The problem seems to be somewhere in my evaluation of the file pointer...

Comment: does `if(file)` work? `NULL` and `0` both cast to `false`

Comment: That is unlikely. Show us full code. what is `res`?

Comment: Your bug is elsewhere.  It's quite possible that the string pointed to by "res" is corrupt.  Try `printf("%s\n", res);` prior to this block of code.

Comment: That's not possible. Something wrong in the previous statement itself when `fopen` access `res`. Ensure that `res` is a valid zero-terminated string.

Comment: It does not, I have tried if(!file) and it does not work. I am trying to test cases where the file does not exist

Comment: The problem is that the file pointer is not evaluating to NULL...right?

Comment: If the file does not exist then file pointer will always have NULL, so it should not crash here.. this part of code is working fine

Comment: @Bubo instead of describing your code, post the *real code*

Comment: It turned out to be the error described by Rosenfield below, I didn't know how the proper way to post all of the code because it is for a GBC emulator that I am working on and is part of a very large block of code. Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `if(file == NULL)` is NOT crashing your program.  If you use a debugger like gdb, it will show you the exact crash location, which is elsewhere.

The reason you probably *think* it's happening there is because you're not printing a newline in your `printf()` call.  By default, when stdout is a terminal, stdout is *line-buffered*, meaning it's not flushed until you print a newline or explicitly flush it yourself with `fflush()`.  But, if your program crashes before it gets flushed, any buffered data gets lost.

Answer (score 2):

You also need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Without that, in C89 `fopen` is considered to return `int`, causing undefined behaviour when you convert it to `FILE *` and dereference. You should get a compiler warning.

In C99 this code is illegal but your compiler might pass it anyway if you aren't invoking in conforming mode.

Answer (score 0):

If I replace the "res" with some random string ("abcd"), the same code works perfectly fine on my machine.
There might be some problem with "res", rest of the code is fit to work.